# Clicking button inside Angular Material's Card triggers the click event of the card itself

Tags: angular

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let p of products" (click)="viewProduct(p)">
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-stroked-button (click)="addProductToCart(p)">Add to cart</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

The issue is that when clicking on the button angular invokes both addProductToCart and viewProduct.

How can i prevent this?

event.stopPropagation() isn't working for me

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` should work, can you show your ts code, with how you used `stopPropagation` ?

Comment: I was wondering If you added a event.stopPropgation to button/mat-card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewProduct` is called as well because of event bubbling. The only stopper here should be `event.stopPropagation()` and it should look something like this

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let p of products" (click)="viewProduct(p)">
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-stroked-button (click)="addProductToCart(p,$event)">Add to cart</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
// Your component code here ...
addProductToCart(p:any,$event:any){
   $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: yes, this should work
https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#stopping-bubbling